# C# - Problems with task results

Tags: c#, winforms, multitasking

I have to find duplicate addresses in a list of 758.000 addresses by string comparison.
What I've done so far:

```
public int StartDuplicateFinder(List<Address> addresses, List<Address> checklist)
{
    int found = 0;

    foreach(Address addr1 in addresses)
    {
        List<Address> addresses2 = checklist.FindAll(
        delegate (Address addr2)
        {
            return addr2.AddressString == addr1.AddressString && addr2.Duplicate == "" 
                && addr2.AddrIndex > addr1.AddrIndex;
        }
        );

        foreach(Address addr2 in addresses2)
        {
            addr2.Duplicate = "1";
            found++;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

This takes about 7 hours (which is too long) and delivers about 93.000 duplicates!

To speed it up I splitted the `checklist` into a `List<Address> checklists` with 4 portions (200k, 200k, 200k and 158k) and used `Task` like this:

```
public class Worker
{
    private List<Address> addresses = null;
    private List<Addresses> checklist = null
    private int found = 0;

    public Worker(List<Address> _addresses, List<Address> _checklist)
    {
        addresses = _addresses; //always 758.000 addresses

        //with 4 Tasks: Task 1, 2 and 3 = 200.000 addresses, Task 4 = 158.000 addresses
        //with 6 Tasks: Task 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 with 150.000 addresses, Task 6 with 8.000 addresses
        checklist = _checklist;
    }

    public int StartDuplicateFinder()
    {
        foreach(Address addr1 in addresses)
        {
            List<Address> addresses2 = checklist.FindAll(
            delegate (Address addr2)
            {
                return addr2.AddressString == addr1.AddressString && addr2.Duplicate == "" 
                    && addr2.AddrIndex > addr1.AddrIndex;
            }
            );

            foreach(Address addr2 in addresses2)
            {
                addr2.Duplicate = "1";
                found++;
            }
        }
    }

    public int Found {get {return found;}}
}

private async void StartTasks(List<Task> Tasklist)
{
    foreach (Task t in Tasklist)
    {
        t.Start();
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(Tasklist.ToArray());
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    List<Task> Tasklist = new List<Task>();

    foreach(List<Address> checklist in checklists)
    {
        Worker w = new Worker(addresses, checklist);
        Tasklist.Add(new Task(StartDuplicateFinder));        
    }
    StartTasks(Tasklist);

    //wait until the tasks are finished
    //do other stuff
    ...
}
```

Now it only runs for 35 minutes! But if i look at the duplicates found there is an enormous deviation. There were only about 27.000 duplicates found.

I tried it several times and every time I get other results.

```
4 Tasks, first run:     4 Tasks, second run:
Task# > duplicates      Task# > duplicates
1     >   749           1     >   689
2     >  2450           2     >  2391
3     > 10304           3     > 10073
4     > 14462           4     > 14282
Sum   > 27965           Sum   > 27435

6 Tasks, first run:     6 Tasks, second run:
Task# > duplicates      Task# > duplicates
1     >    16           1     >    24
2     >    56           2     >    55
3     >   202           3     >   236
4     >   679           4     >   634
5     >   852           5     >   800
6     >  2985           6     >  2981
Sum   >  4790           Sum   >  4730
```

Every time it's the same list of 758.000 addresses.

I tried it with `Task`, `Thread` and `BackgroundWorker` but I always get different results!
If i run this in 1 Task the result is always 92.377 duplicates (which I think is correct).

Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Comment: Please post your code that builds and executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not enough code in the question to speculate.  If you really want to troubleshoot, you'll need a complete, self-contained repo.  But the typical cause of this kind of behavior is that you're modifying shared data in multiple threads.  As a rule of thumb parallel workers should operate over read-only data, returning their results to be accumulated by the main thread.

But instead of parallel processing, consider using more efficient data structures and algorithms.  IE instead of a nested loops join, build a Hash Table (`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` or `Lookup<TKey,TValue>`) to make this faster on a single thread (at least as a first step).  EG something like:

```
public int StartDuplicateFinder(List<Address> addresses, List<Address> checklist)
{
    int found = 0;

    var checklistByAddressString = checklist.ToLookup(a => a.AddressString, a => a);

    foreach (Address addr1 in addresses)
    {
        var addressMatches = checklistByAddressString[addr1.AddressString];
        var addresses2 = addressMatches.Where(addr2 => addr2.Duplicate == ""
                && addr2.AddrIndex > addr1.AddrIndex);

        foreach (Address addr2 in addresses2)
        {
            addr2.Duplicate = "1";
            found++;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are modifying items in `addresses` list while you're looping through them. You are creating race conditions.

Your filter has, as the part of criteria:

```cs
addr2.Duplicate == ""
```

While later you alter the items:

```cs
addr2.Duplicate = "1"`.
```

Perhaps would be better that you chunk `addresses` and go against full `checkList`

Or, just use `LINQ query` on the single thread against both list. You will most likely get drastically faster results then manually looping through collections.